# How to Limit Substring size in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get all the substring starting with character 'm' and having 5 character. I tried with this code, but its not working.

```
<code>
import re
str1 = "mouseeee mother mouse is beautiful creation"
r = re.compile("m[a-z]{5}$")
print(r.findall(str1))</code>
```

Comment: What do you think the $ does?

Comment: Use `\b` instead of `$`. You might also want to add a `\b` in front of the `m`.

Comment: Do you need to get *words* starting with `m`? Or really any `m` with exactly 5 lowercase letters after it? Then, just remove `$` (end of string anchor). See https://ideone.com/BqGdI3

Comment: I want the words starting with small m and having 5 character in it.

Comment: So, only `mother` should be output, right?

Comment: Yes, Exactly...

Comment: So, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract words starting with small `m` and having 5 character in them, use

```
import re
str1 = "mouseeee mother mouse is beautiful creation"
r = re.compile(r"\bm[a-z]{5}\b")
print(r.findall(str1)) # => ['mother']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BqGdI3). `mouseeee` has more than 6 letters and `mouse` has got 4 letters after the initial `m`, so those are not matched.

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `m` - an `m`
- `[a-z]{5}` - 5 ASCII lowercase letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

To make the pattern case insensitive, pass `re.I` flag to the `re.compile`.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: added suggestions by Wiktor Stribiżew*

If you want to get all separate words of exactly length 6 starting with the letter m, you could use:

```
r = re.compile(r"(?<!\w)(m[a-z]{5})(?!\w)")
```

This ensures a non-letter-char before and after the match (with negative lookback and lookahead), which consists of the letter `m` followed by 5 other letters. The negative lookahead can be simplified by using `\b` for word boundaries, as presented in the other answers.

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = "mouseeee mother mouse is beautiful creation"
>>> r = re.compile("(?<= )(m[a-z]{5})(?= )")
>>> print(r.findall(str1))
['mother']
```

Comment: This will also match the space though… And it will only work with spaces…

Comment: output was ['mousee', 'mother']

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to simulate `\b`, use `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)`

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't got this simulation thing ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, edited my answer. ViralParmar: I changed my test string back to your example, it should match your expected output now.

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* want the regex `\bm[a-z]{5}\b` (\b is the word boundary escape sequence)

Currently, in your regex $ denotes the end of the string. In addition, there's nothing in there to prevent the matching from starting in the middle of a word.

```
>>> str1 = "mouseeee mother mouse is beautiful creation"
>>> r = re.compile(r"\bm[a-z]{5}\b")
>>> r.findall(str1)
['mother']
```

Comment: Thank you ! Working perfectly!

Comment: @ViralParmar no problem. Please consider accepting one of the answers that helped you (not necessarily mine) by clicking the green checkmark next to it.